# Apply change when editing a mediawiki skin

Tags: mediawiki, skinning

I am editing a mediawiki skin but the change doesn't appear in my browser.

Is there a way to force the *myskin.php* to see the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending

> ?action=purge

to the URL, to clear the server-side cache.